# How to use Eclipse for remote debugging of a Google App Engine (GAE) application

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, remote-debugging

Is there a way to debug (specifically step-through) a Google app engine application that has been deployed to the cloud. The reason I am asking is that there are certain things that either cannot be debugged locally or require work-arounds to test locally (eg. CRON Jobs).

Specifically I want to do this using Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** as of 2015 it is possible to debug AppEngine Java applications if they run on Managed VMs. Also, the debugger is a web-based hosted debugger - no support yet for your popular IDE. See [Cloud Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/).

No, this can not be done.

One of the reasons why this most probably will never be available is that GAE is a distributed cloud system, where an "application" can have multiple instances running in parallel and there is no guarantee that consequent requests (e.g. a user session) would be served by the same instance. So there would be no way to know to which instance to connect debugger to.

Comment: Well if they can do traffic splitting to test out new versions and direct to a particular version based on cookie or ip, they could apply that principle and route to a debug instance that only and always handles debug requests.  Alls they would have to do is ensure the debug version only runs one instance.

Comment: That was then (2012) is it still true today (2013)?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to star this [acknowledged bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2292)